# Why is the page number on title page formatted differently?

Tags: page-numbering

I want to have my page numbers in orange and of size footnotesize. Why does the following not produce that result on the title page? I am willing to entertain two solutions: either suppress the page numbers on the title page, or start with correctly formatted page numbering at section A.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \textcolor{orange}{\thepage}}% P
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\title{Title goes here}
\author{Author goes here}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{A} Section A text.
    \newpage
    \section{B} Section B text.
    \newpage
    \section{C} Section C text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because `\maketitle` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` internally

Comment: if the first page is really just for a title  you can type `{\renewcommand{\thepage}{\huge \textcolor{orange}{\arabic{page}}}
    \maketitle
    \newpage}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\maketitle` of the `article.cls` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`. If this is not wanted either `plain` has to be redefined, `\maketitle` be redefined or one could use `\xpatchcmd` to replace the `plain` with `mypagestyle` here.

```
  \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}}{}{}
```

Since the O.P. does set the pagestyle globally to `mypagestyle` at the beginning,

```
  \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}{}
```

would do also, i.e. replacing it with nothing. The first method is 'safer', however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter


\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% 
  \fancyfoot[C]{\huge \textcolor{orange}{\thepage}}% P
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother

% Patch the plain out of \maketitle
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}}{}{}


\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\title{Title goes here}
\author{Author goes here}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{A} Section A text.
    \newpage
    \section{B} Section B text.
    \newpage
    \section{C} Section C text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why replace it? Why not just remove it (i.e. replace with nothing)?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Just for the case that `mypagestyle` is not set from the beginning?

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose, but OP *is* setting the pagestyle globally :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: I include the case that the OP just forgot to do so :-P

Comment: `\footnotesize` has been replaced to make the number more outstanding here, just for demonstration